# Cassandra with Workflow Engine

Tags: java, cassandra, workflow, bpel

We are setting up a new process system in which we monitor process execution. We use cassandra for the monitoring part - now we are thinking about also exchanging our old execution engine.

In this situation we are thinking, whether it might be possible to also use cassandra.

Is there a java workflow engine or bpel tool that can use Cassandra as it's database?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any BPEL engine. I know that a customer of Camunda BPM is conducting some experiments with Cassandra and [blogged about it](http://blog.camunda.org/2015/03/camunda-meets-cassandra-zalando.html), also about the implications.

Since most workflows engines are very transactional and based on relational schemas, I assume the transition to Cassandra is not that straight-forward.